# I want to save the result of the command as a variable in window batch

Tags: batch-file

I try use the `for /f` statement to get the command result like `error : file not found` but this code `%_result% return null`

How do I get the result of the command?

Here is my code:

```
SET CML=forfiles /p %BAKPATH% /M *.zip /D -10 /C "CMD /C del @file"

FOR /F "tokens=* USEBACKQ" %%F IN (
'%CML%'
) DO (
SET _result=%%F
)

echo result = %_result%
```

Comment: use `for` either without `usebackq` and `... in ('straight single quotes') do` or with `usebackq` and with `... in (\`backticks\`) do`

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! What do you mean exactly by "result"? Do you mean the  [exit status](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exit_status) of the program or do you mean the output that is written on screen (standard out/standard err)? If you want the exit code,  you can obtain it using the `%ERRORLEVEL%` variable.

Comment: i try to for without `usebackq` but it same return empty and i try to use single quotes and backtick but single quotes was same and backticks return `
The file `forfiles' could not be found.`

Comment: I want to handle the exception except for the error that the file can not be found.

Comment: when i use `%ERRORLEVEL%` like `if not "%ERRORLEVEL%" == "0" goto ERROR2` 
If i get an error that the file can not be found, run the goto statement.
I trying not to execute the goto statement when a file not found error occurs.

Comment: So you want to see the actual error instead of the errorlevel?

Comment: Yes, I want to know the exact error with the text. Or Distinction 'the file could not be found' and 'other errors'.

Comment: thank a lot, i'll get a error msg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is a little unclear, but seems you want to use the actual error message and store it as a variable.

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('forfiles /p %bakpath% /M *.zip /D -10 /C "CMD /C del @file" 2^>^&1') do set "_result=%%a"
echo %_result%
```

Comment: Note: this keeps just the latest error message (first because of `2 >error.txt`, second because of the `for` loop). Even worse: if the last operation is successfull, there will be no errormessage at all, even if all others would fail.

Comment: Maybe just `forfiles /p .\ /M *.zip /C "CMD /C del @file" 2>&1|find /i /v "*.zip"`

Comment: @Stephan, yes, you are correct. I updated using your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach that would be to redirect `stderr` (where most commands send their error messages) to `stdout` so that it can be captured by the `for /f` command. Using:

```
@echo off
setlocal
set BAKPATH=.

SET CML=forfiles /p %BAKPATH% /M *.zip /D -10 /C "CMD /C del @file"

FOR /F "tokens=* USEBACKQ" %%F IN (
`"%CML% 2>&1"`
) DO (
SET _result=%%F
)

echo result = %_result%
```

where I've added `2>&1` to the command-invocation. The `2>` part says we want to redirect file-descriptor `2` (aka `stderr`); the `&1` part says to redirect it to file-descriptor `1` (aka `stdout`). To protect the `>` and `&` characters, the whole command has been enclosed in double-quotes (`"..."`) and to match the use of `usebackq` the outer `'...'` has been changed to `` `...` ``.

With no suitable ZIP file present, this gives:

```
result = ERROR: No files found with the specified search criteria.
```

but with one or more 10-day or older ZIP files in place, it gives an empty string:

```
result =
```